# How to read files from a subfolder present under nested parent folder using azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

How to read files from a subfolder present under nested parent folder using azure data factory?

```
Container/ABC/Transcation/07654/Audit/Report.csv

Container/CDF/Transcation/07654/Audit/Tranfee/report0910201.csv

Container/FGS/Transcation/07654/Audit/custom/report08092021.csv
```

I want to retrieve all the files(including the files under subfolder) Under the Audit folder.

Answer (score 0):

While creating dataset specify the folder path.

[image]

In source configuration enable `Recursively` option.

[image]